# Detect from CD pipeline the cause of the CI trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

In my Azure DevOps pipeline, when a PR (from feature branches to dev branch) or a direct push against the dev branch (DevOps engineer has 'force push' privileges) occurs, a CI build automatically gets triggered. As soon as the build finishes, a CD pipeline starts (continuous integration enabled).

Is there a way from the CD pipeline (PowerShell) to detect if the CI build was triggered from a PR or a direct push?
`RELEASE_REASON` says Manual or ContinuousIntegration which does not help in my case.

Using the REST API to get the build details says `"reason": "individualCI"` which does not help neither.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to get the reason of the build trigger:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}?api-version=5.1
```

I test with post man ,if the cause of the build is CI, the reason of the build will be individualCI

[image][image]

If the cause of the build is pull request, the reason of the build will be pull request.
[image][image]

**Note** that if you enable continuous integration and set the pr trigger build in the branch policy, then when you create a pr to trigger build, the build pipeline actually runs two builds, one triggered by creating PR, the other is the ci build triggered by the change of the target branch after the pr is completed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sadly for me, both cases have "individualCI". I tried the first scenario when PR was accepted/completed then automatically merged. The other case was a direct push to the branch without PR. Maybe "pullRequest" appears only during CI validation build?

Comment: The pull request appears because you set up the Build validation in the branch policies. Once the pr is created, the build will be triggered by the pr. Even if you disbale ci, pull reuqest can still appear.